# perform iteration in StringTemplate4 (C#)

Tags: c#, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

In the StringTemplate4 cheat sheet (http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet), it mentions that to perform an iteration

```
<attribute:{anonymous-template}>
Apply an anonymous template to each element of attribute. The iterated `it` attribute is set automatically.
```

I have tried the below code:

```
        List<TextParseTests.TestModel> data = new List<TextParseTests.TestModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TextParseTests.TestModel model2 = new TextParseTests.TestModel();
            model2.Name = i.ToString();
            data.Add(model2);
        }


        string template = @"TestTemplate|| <List:{ [DataList <it.Name>]  }> [END]";

        Template t = new Template(template);
        t.Add("List", data.ToArray());


        var result = t.Render();
        sb.AppendLine(result);
```

**Update 1**

Below are the TestModel data structure and related classes.  I am using these just

```
    public class ContactDetailsTest
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public ContactDetailsTest ContactDetails { get; set; }

        public TestModel()
        {
            this.ContactDetails = new ContactDetailsTest();
        }
    }
```

---

Yet the end result is:

```
"TestTemplate||  [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [DataList ]   [END]"
```

It does get iterated 10 times, however the variable `it` does not seem to have been populated.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show what a `TextParseTests.TestModel` looks like? Specifically the constructor?

Comment: @kelton52 just added information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your template to this

```
TestTemplate|| <List:{x | [DataList <x.Name>]  }> [END]
```

As of this documentation

```
<attribute:{x | anonymous-template}>
Apply an anonymous template to each element of attribute.  
The iterated value is set to argument x. 
The anonymous template references <x> to access the iterator value.
```

You can set `x` to anything you like, it's just a place holder for the iterator.

The problem was that you were using the StringTemplate3 cheatsheet instead of the StringTemplate4 cheatsheet http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet

Comment: that did the trick, thanks for pointing out my mistake of using the ST3 cheatsheet rather than ST4!

Comment: [This page](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/Differences+between+v3+and+v4) lists the differences between StringTemplate v3 and 4, to quote: _There is no implicit it or attr attribute during generation now._  Helped me out!

Comment: All of these links are broken or require an Atlassian account